# image not appear, img base64 decode not working

Tags: php, apache, base64, decode, encode

After moving to a new server, many function of my apps are not working. It works again after installing some PHP extension, but this one is still not working. I never changed anything in my app because I'm not good at coding.

```
<img src="http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/gallery/'.base64_encode('../media/'.md5($cm.'manf').'/'.$t['photos']).'/'.$cm.'/'.$t['name'].'.png"/>
```

Image is not showing on my page. Honestly, that `base64_encode` value is correct. I've tried to decode its value on https://www.base64decode.org/ and the result is correct.
The problem is: why that value is not rewritten to img url source? Still trying to figure it out, maybe the problem is not in the code, but on my web-server or something else.
Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: You need to decode or encode ?

Comment: i'm not sure, that should decoded on img url so the image appear, right ?

Comment: Yes, but you use encode.

Comment: The apps not made by me and the apps working fine before, No code changed.

Comment: If you didin't change nothing how is possible now not work? Or the data is not correct or the code changed.

Comment: Like i said, after moving to a new server problem occur. If I paste decoded value to address bar and the image appear.

Comment: it's http or https the new?

Comment: It's use http, change to https still same